# Windows 10 UWP: How to set different logos at start menu , taskbar & app list

Tags: windows, uwp

I noticed that in some UWP apps such as Wunderlist and Twitter, the app logo is different in different location:

- At start menu:

[image: at start menu]

- At app list:

[image: at app list]

How can I achieve different logos at start menu , taskbar & app list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following logos are used in different cases in UWP apps:

- **start menu**: tile images and logos in different sizes for different sizes of tiles (different scales are used for different screen DPI):

  - square 71x71: small tile
  - square 150x150: medium tile
  - wide 310x150: wide tile
  - square 310x310: large tile
- **app list**: square 44x44 tile logo is used
- **taskbar**: square 44x44 tile logo is used, in matching target size in pixels, if available

I suggest you [download the sample UWP Visual Assets app by Paul Thomson from GitHub](https://github.com/paulthomson64/uwp-visual-assets) and try it out. It has a different logo for each size, making it easy to determine which one is used in each case.

You can also try clicking on different logos in the `Package.appxmanifest` editor in Visual Studio. A message dialog will pop up, describing where the logo will be used:

[image: Dialog describing where the logo will be used]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried the sample myself and that working. And is it possible to use different logos in app list and taskbar? Just like Microsoft Edge at desktop, whose taskbar logo is blue/transparent(foreground/background) and app list logo is white/blue.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to see that even in the sample app. On my machine the app list uses `Square 44x44 logo (scale 100)` (yellow square with `S44 100` written on it), and the taskbar uses `Square 44x44 logo (target size 44)` (square with its top hlaf black and its bottom half purple).

Comment: To have a transparent background in the task bar, you should use the `unplated` tile image filename modifier, see: http://metronuggets.com/2015/07/01/using-unplated-tile-images-in-uwp-apps/ . This [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt412102.aspx) also sums it up quite good.